# Clojure Macros: Accumulate value over scope

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm studing macros and as project example building an route system. An **route** (functions get/post/put/...) can be attached to an **scope**, when it occurs the **route url** is prefixed by the actual scope, example:

```
;; base scope macro
(defmacro scope [url & body]
  `(let [~'base-scope ~url
         ~'get #(str ~'base-scope %)]
     ~@body))

(scope "admin/"
  (get "stackoverflow")) ;; OK! returns 'admin/stackoverflow'
```

The problem is that scope can be nested:

```
(scope "admin/"
  (scope "api/"
    (get "stackoverflow")))
```

My question is: How can I make a lookup under the actual scope, searching for route prefixes(scopes)? I know that I have access to **&env** and **&form** implicits; should I use **&env** and try to create a kind of hidden prefixes, or use &form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use dynamic bindings – have a Var initially bound to `[]` and `conj` scopes on to it in `scope`-emitted `binding` forms. Overall it should be pretty straightforward, and also limited in some ways – you'd have to be careful about the dynamic extent / lifetime of your bindings.

If you're after something lexically scoped, you could use [tools.macro](https://github.com/clojure/tools.macro)'s local macros to redefine `scope` invocations nested within other `scope` invocations. (In that case I would factor out as much of the actual logic into a helper function or two.)

As a very straightforward alternative, you could introduce a distinguished local name – preferably generated using `gensym` – and use it in `scope`'s expansion much like the dynamic binding of the distinguished Var in the approach described above. The difference is that here the scopes would actually be lexically scoped. There's at least one caveat in that evil user code in the body could access or shadow the distinguished local – it's pretty unlikely with a `gensym`, though not that difficult if one feels like breaking things. The key point, though, is that one might be justified in feeling uncomfortable about "globally magic locals".

Finally, you could also introduce fresh "locally magic locals" in each expansion and search for them in `&env`. Here's a simple proof of concept using metadata to mark the magic locals:

```
(defmacro scope [sname & body]
  (let [scopes (filterv #(contains? (meta %) :scope) (keys &env))
        maybe-printout (if (seq scopes)
                         [(list* `println scopes)])]
    `(let [~(with-meta (gensym "scope__") {:scope true}) '~sname]
       ~@maybe-printout
       ~@body)))
```

At the REPL,

```
(scope :foo
  (scope :bar
    (scope :quux
      (scope :xyz))))
```

prints out

```
:foo
:foo :bar
:foo :bar :quux
```

returning `nil`.

`(set! *print-meta* true)` and a `macroexpand` call reveal that the above expands to

```
(let* [^{:scope true} scope__16668 (quote :foo)]
  ^{:line 4, :column 6}
  (scope :bar
    ^{:line 5, :column 8}
    (scope :quux
      ^{:line 6, :column 10}
      (scope :xyz))))
```

Of course only the `:scope` metadata is interesting. If it's ok to assume that scope names must be compile-time constants, it's even possible to retrieve their actual values at compile time (see `clojure.lang.Compiler$LocalBinding` and `clojure.lang.Compiler$ConstantExpr`), but that'd be an unnecessary hack in this case.

This doesn't solve the whole problem as written – rather than creating new individual "scope locals", `scope` should probably maintain locals with growing vectors of scope names to preserve ordering. This can be done e.g. by searching for a `:scope`-tagged local and shadowing it if it exists (if not, we're in a top-level `scope` and a new local should be created).

Comment: NB. the `:scope` keyword should be namespaced if anything like the above "locally magic locals" approach is used in a library.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very explicative! I tried something similar to your last example using &env and defining an local , but I didn't realize how get the other scopes, thanks for the help.